# Select only one row from table with the highest datetime value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks similar to this:

```
images
    image_id       int
    user_id        int
    datetime       datetime
```

So, I need to get only one result. This result should have a specific user_id and should only be the most recent row in the table.

I've checked out many similar questions, but wasn't able to understand how to do it and the codes I found didn't work at all.

How can I achieve this?

Here's a start query:

```
SELECT *
FROM image
WHERE user_id = :user_id
```

How do I change this query to select only the most recent row with a specific user_id?

Comment: add this line at the end `order by datetime desc limit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use order by clause like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM image
WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can use:

```
SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM image
WHERE user_id = :user_id 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Comment: Top is for mssql not in mysql

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL try the following:

> SELECT * FROM image
>   WHERE user_id = :user_id
>   ORDER BY datetime DESC
>   **limit 1**

`limit` will work with MySQL

For further info on MySql statements look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

Select * from images
       where User_id = :User_id Order by datetime DESC
                        Limit 1

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

By using limit you can get no.of required data

```
limit required_no.
```